# Mass Check-in not working because of missing fields

Tags: 2010, list, document, check-out, check-in

I'm trying to check in a couple hundred docs after I've uploaded them. They're all in the checkout state. However I get an error saying

```
You must fill out all required properties before checking in this document
```

Upon further investigation, I found that the `Title` is not populated which is stopping the check-in.

Is there a way to auto-fill the fields when a document is uploaded?

Comment: I would do what Chris G suggested. But you can write a workflow that will populate the title field automatically when a document is uploaded. Or use datasheet view to add titles where they're missing.

Answer (score 2):

Is the "Title" the only other column in the library? If so go to the library settings and make the column not required.

This usually happens where there are other content types or columns in the library.

If you were to make a workflow with this here is one you can run on one item at a time to show you it is possible to catch and update this when new items are added etc. Looping logic would need to be added if you wanted to update many items biased on a count or something else.

Example:
If the "title" field is empty update it with the value from the "Name" column. (the 'name' column is what the document name is.)
[image]